# AngularJS CSS list animation

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm having trouble figuring out some basic AngularJS 1.4+CSS animation stuff.

I have a list where new items always enter at the top and exit at the bottom when a max number of items has been reached (5 in the example below).

The following code successfully does a fade animation for this scenario:

```js
angular.module("testApp", ["ngAnimate"])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    var lastId = 0;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.add = function() {
      if (!$scope.newValue) { return; }
      $scope.items.unshift({id: ++lastId, name:$scope.newValue});
      $scope.newValue = '';
      while ($scope.items.length > 5) {
        $scope.items.pop();
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.list-item.ng-enter {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.list-item.ng-leave {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newValue" />
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

However a fade isn't really what I'm after.  I want the added items to expand in height as if sliding in from the top, the exiting items to reduce in height as if sliding out the bottom, and the retained items to slide downwards to move to their new positions.  But I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I've tried just using the `height` property in place of `opacity`, but that doesn't seem to work very well.  Also note that I'd prefer not to specify a height explicitly for the final result, but let that autosize with the font as usual.  (Which might be part of my problem.)

The height changing is definitely my preferred method, but it would probably also be ok if it were a pure slide, with the entered items fading in and the leaving items fading out as well.  However in both cases it's essential that it not alter the size of the parent element or any surrounding elements on the page (except when not removing an element when the list is first growing, of course).

(Normally only one item will enter and leave at a time, but there might be occasions when two items enter and/or leave.  It'd be nice if the animation could delay appropriately so that they appear to slide in sequence as you'd expect, but I'm ok with not doing that if it's too complicated.)

It may also be worth mentioning that in a previous iteration of the page I was using jQuery animations "slideUp" to remove items and "slideDown" to add them -- in that order, since I was also manually inserting/removing items (this was pre-Angular).  It worked quite well, and I'm trying to replicate that effect, although I'm not sure if CSS animations (or ng-repeat) support controlling the animation order like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more experimentation, the code below seems to work.

Key changes:

- Tables don't seem to animate very well.  Using `<li>` instead seems to work better.
- `overflow-y: hidden` is needed in addition to animating `max-height`.

```js
angular.module("testApp", ["ngAnimate"])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    var lastId = 0;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.add = function() {
      if (!$scope.newValue) { return; }
      $scope.items.unshift({id: ++lastId, name:$scope.newValue});
      $scope.newValue = '';
      while ($scope.items.length > 5) {
        $scope.items.pop();
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.list-item.ng-enter {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  max-height: 20px;
}
.list-item.ng-leave {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  max-height: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newValue" />
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```